Can someone explain what "outputFromObservable" is in Angular? Where would you use this, and what are some potential use cases for it?
https://angular.dev/guide/signals/rxjs-interop#outputfromobservable
This is very difficult for me to understand. There is not much example available here.
public count:OutputRef<number> = outputFromObservable(this.countObservable$);
  public output3 = output()

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.count.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
  }

If i use this outputFormObservable I get only one method for the count variable that is to subscribe. Sill why ? I mean we can directly subscribe from the observable ?

it can be really anything that your mind can imagine when you have rxjs stream in the component and you want to produce output events from this stream to notify something outside of the component.
just as an example - forms
class MyFormComponent
  form = new FormGroup(...) // any content
  formChanges = outputFromObservable(this.form.valueChanges);
}
...
<my-form (formChanges)="handleFormChanges($event)">

